# Need help correcting - erratic atoi() output

Tags: c, gcc, atoi

I am trying to convert a string of int into an array of int.

Here is my code :

```
int premaster1 = 3255859;
char hashString[100];
int hashStringInput[1000];

sprintf(hashString,"%d%d%d",premaster1,300,350);
printf("\n message going inside hash function = %s\n",hashString);


for(i=0;i<strlen(hashString)+1;i++){
    hashStringInput[i] = atoi(&hashString[i]);
    printf("%d",hashStringInput[i]);
}
```

here is my output :

```
message going inside hash function = 3255859300350
274089982-18387374102472550215643330548593003505930035093003503003503503503505000
```

which is obviously wrong. My desire output should be :

```
message going inside hash function = 3255859300350
3255859300350
```

What am I doing wrong and how may I fix it?

Comment: Regarding the question you just deleted - I hope I didn't turn you away! Just try and code up a solution to your problem, and come back with a more specific question if you have any issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing entire strings to atoi:

```
"3255859300350" // First loop iteration
"255859300350"  // Second loop iteration
"55859300350"
"5859300350"
// And so on...
```

One solution is to use temporary buffer in loop:

```
char temp [2] = { 0, 0 }; // Second element is for NUL character
temp[0] = hashString[i];  // Copy first char
hashStringInput[i] = atoi(temp);
```

Also, don't use `+1` with your `strlen`, you don't want to convert the NUL character.

Comment: ok I tried this `char z; z= hashString[i];
  hashStringInput[i] = atoi(z);` now i get a compiler error : `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`

Comment: @sukhvir It must be `z[0]`, not `z`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of below statement

```
   hashStringInput[i] = atoi(&hashString[i]);
```

Use this statement

```
   hashStringInput[i] =hashString[i]-'0';
```

Specifically In your case you can use as above and this converts ascii digit to integer digit.

```
  Example '3' to 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code just makes no sense. The `atoi` function converts a string into an integer. So why are you passing it individual characters?

**Update**: You don't have a large integer. You have a string of digits. Digits represent a number from 0 to 9 inclusive, which is not large at all. And if you did have a large integer, you would never be calling `atoi` because that converts *strings* to integers.

Your code, `sprintf(hashString,"%d%d%d",premaster1,300,350);` creates a string of decimal digits from three integers. That's, I assume, why you call it hash*String*. It is not a large integer. Do not confuse numbers with their textual representations. Programmers must keep these things straight or pain will result. Half the solution is understanding the problem.

Comment: because i am trying to covert the number inside hashString to individual elements of hashStringInput by puting each digit as a separate element

Comment: Then don't use `atoi`. The `atoi` function is specifically for converting *strings* (of decimal digits) to integers, not numbers, not characters.

Comment: how else may I go about converting a large intiger like 3255859300350 into elements of an int array with each element as separate digit

Comment: You can use ASCII value of char in the string to find its integer value, store that in the integer array.

Comment: @Anirudh could you give me a sample as to how to do that ?

Comment: Thanks @DavidSchwartz .. I was already aware of the fact that stuff inside hashString is a string not a large int. Its my bad, typo in my original post

Comment: @sukhvir Good. So now you know that you have a string of decimal digits. You want to convert each decimal digit to the number, from 0 to 9 inclusive, that it represents.

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` takes a `char*` and converts it to an integer. However your integer is larger than the maximum value that can be represented by an `int`. This causes undefined behaviour (in your case `atoi` returns 0x7fffffff for the first `int`)